# Can one define a separate css file for an extending html template in Django?

Tags: html, css, django, django-templates

Assume that abc.html extends base.html in a django app.

I noticed that I have to do the styling of abc.html inside the css file of base.html (say base.css)

I was wondering there is a way to define a separate (independent) css file for abc.html and manage the styling using base.css and abc.css files for example? I tried to follow the same steps to use ,  and  tags inside abc.html and define a link to abc.css file, but django was not picking it up.

Answer (score -1):

Have a block inside your base.html containing your CSS file.
Example:

```
{% block base.css %}
```

When you extend your base.html, replace the content within block with your new css file.

Or use `{{ block.super }}` after abc.html css.

Hope it helps.